# Returning distinct list of IDs existings in all subsets

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.0

I have two tables

```
Table "public.tags_to_entities"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 tid    | integer | not null
 eid    | integer | not null

   Table "public.tag_tree"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 tid    | integer | not null
 pid    | integer | not null
 level  | integer |
```

`tag_tree` contains all relations between tags, meaning `SELECT pid FROM tag_tree WHERE tid = ?` would return that tag's parents. The `level` column is there or `ORDER BY` only.

I want to return a list of all `eid` that have at least one tag in every subset of tags. Doing one subset works using the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT eid
FROM tags_to_entities
WHERE
    tags_to_entities.tid = 1 OR
    tags_to_entities.tid IN (SELECT tag_tree.tid FROM tag_tree WHERE tag_tree.pid = 1));
```

This returns all `eid` existing in tag 1 or one of its child tags. If I want to return all `eid` existing in at least one of the tags related to `1` **and** `2`. My failed approach so far is

```
SELECT DISTINCT eid
FROM tags_to_entities
WHERE
    (
        tags_to_entities.tid = 1 OR
        tags_to_entities.tid IN (SELECT tag_tree.tid FROM tag_tree WHERE tag_tree.pid = 1)) AND
    (
        tags_to_entities.tid = 2 OR
        tags_to_entities.tid IN (SELECT tag_tree.tid FROM tag_tree WHERE tag_tree.pid = 2));
```

This won't work since a tid can't be both 1 and 2 simultaneously. How can I solve this? (The eid will be joined with the entries table later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`.  This allows you to use aggregate functions, and a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT
  map.eid
FROM
  tags_to_entities    AS map
INNER JOIN
  tag_tree            AS tree
    ON map.tid = tree.tid
WHERE
     (tree.tid = 1 OR tree.pid = 1)
  OR (tree.tid = 2 OR tree.pid = 2)
GROUP BY
  map.id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (tree.tid = 1 OR tree.pid = 1) THEN 1
                      WHEN (tree.tid = 2 OR tree.pid = 2) THEN 2
                 END)
  = 2
```

The `JOIN` and `WHERE` clause get all entities where they have tag `1` ***or*** `2`.  But then you group them together, and then count up how many different categories those tags are in.  Only if it's 2 does the entity get through the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Is `GROUP BY map.id` supposed to be _eid_ or _tid_, I assume _eid_?

Comment: Switching `GROUP BY map.id` to `GROUP BY map.eid` and it works just as intended. Thank you!

Comment: @antennen - yup, sorry, `eid` ;)